# Searching 2D numpy array of ids for partial id

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, filter

I have the following 2 arrays:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                [5, 6, 7, 8], 
                [7, 5, 6, 3],
                [2, 4, 8, 9]]

 ids = np.array([6, 5])
```

Each row in the array `arr` describes a 4-digit id, there are no redundant ids - neither in their values nor their combination. So if `[1, 2, 3, 4]` exists, no other combination of these 4 digits can exist. This will be important in a sec.

The array `ids` contains a 2-digit id, however the order is random. Now I need to go through each row of `arr` and look if this 2-digit partial id part of any 4-digit id. In this example `ids` fits to the 2nd and 3rd row from the top of `arr`.

My current solution with `np.isin` only works if the array `ids` has also a 4-digit row.

```
arr[np.isin(arr, ids).all(1)]
```

Changing `all(1)` to `any(1)` doesn´t do the trick either, because this way it would be enough if just one digit of `ids` is in one row of `arr`, however I need both values.

Does anyone have a compact solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need the boolean index to only accept values that are `2`.  When doing non-boolean operations like `sum` with boolean arrays, `True` and `False` values are interpreted as  `1` and `0`

```
arr[np.isin(arr, ids).sum(1) == 2]
```